# Does Completable Future uses ReactiveRequest internally?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

My code uses Completable Future for aynchronous programming.
The question here is whether Completable Future uses ReactiveRequest internally which comes from 
org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-reactive-httpclient dependency.
As I am not willing to use this dependency.

Comment: Simple hint, does your code compile if you **not** include such dependency?

Answer (score 3):

No, [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) is bundled in the JDK itself and does not have any dependency on any external jar.

Comment: okay...Can you tell me how org.eclipse.jetty.reactive.client.ReactiveRequest is used by Completable future internally....because in my code this is used by Completable Future.

Comment: Like I said above CompletableFuture does not have any dependency on any external jar classes other than those in the JDK itself. What makes you believe CompletableFuture internally uses `org.eclipse.jetty.reactive.client.ReactiveRequest` ?

Comment: Yes Completablefuture is not using it ...but I am pretty sure it's being used by WebClient..is it true??

Comment: @harsh What do you mean "used by WebClient"? Other libraries, regardless of which ones, may use `CompletableFuture` but `CompletableFuture` is _entirely contained_ within the JDK.